# Update database based on radio button value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to create a rating system for a website. Im able to retrieve the items from the database and display 5 radio buttons under each item. The 5 radio buttons have the values 1 to 5.

Im trying to update the rating of each item based on the value of the radio button thats selected.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) { 
     $i=0;
     echo '<table><tr>';

     echo '<br/>';
     echo '<br/>';

     while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {   
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" id = "programmes" action="">';
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"progID\" value=\"".htmlentities($obj->ProgrammeID)."\" />";
        echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="progRating"><h4>'.$obj->Rating.'</h4></div>';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="2">';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="3">';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="4">';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="5">';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</td>';
        $i++; 
        if ($i == 5 OR $i == 10) {
          echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
     echo '</tr></table>';
}



    if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
        $newRating = $_POST['rate'];
        $ID = $_POST['progID'];

        $upsql = "UPDATE programmes SET Rating = Rating + $newRating WHERE ProgrammeID='$ID'";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

?>
```

All of the code works fine except for the Update statement where im adding to the current rating that is already stored in the database.

Can someone help me on how to fix this issue

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Possibly the problem is that yout code does not include any `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: why is it `rating + $newrating`? If the previous rating was (say) `3`, and the user has selected `5`, you'll end up with `8` in your DB, which is a pretty rating for a 1-5 scale. And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB Sorry i might need to make that a bit clearer. The values for the radio buttons are 1-5 the ratings within the database will keep adding based on the values

Comment: @syck The update code is at the bottom of my post. It doesnt do anything. Nothing happens when i click on either of the radio buttons

Comment: oh. so it's a running total of everyone's individual ratings? gotcha.  In any case, if the update isn't working, then figure out why: mysqli defaults to returning boolean false on failure, and your code simply assuming success. `$res = mysqli_query(...); if ($res === false) { die(mysqli_error($con)); }`-type stuff makes it a LOT easier to find out why/where something barfed.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah exactly! a running total. I tried the if ($res === false) part but still nothing happens. I dont get any errors either.

Comment: ah yes: you have no form field named `minus`, so your `if($_POST['minus'])` will never EVER evalute to true, skipping the entire update section.

Comment: @MarcB Ah yeah "minus" was a button i had originally but i've since removed that and replaced it with the 5 radio buttons called "rate". I tryed to POST rate but that still didnt do anything

Comment: @Akshay The update statement isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be catching error conditions, this will tell you what, if anything, is wrong with your statement. Also you should be using prepared statements properly to avoid security problems. Finally, you should do your database insert before displaying the data, to ensure you're showing the latest data.

```
if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
    $upsql = "UPDATE programmes SET Rating = Rating + ? WHERE ProgrammeID = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "Error preparing: " . $mysqli->error . "<br/>";
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $_POST['rate'], $_POST['progID']);
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error executing: " . $mysqli->error . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo $stmt->affected_rows . "rows affected<br/>";
        }
    }
}

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) { 
...
```